# How to use both custom scss and boostrap css in the className Ract JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`import styles from '../styles/filterableTable.scss';`

Then view

```
 return (
    <div >
        <p className={'text-success' +  styles.ff}>Uthaya</p> 
        <input
            value={filter}
            ref={node => {input = node;}}
            onChange={() => onFilter(input.value)} />

        <ProductTable filter={filter} />
    </div>
);
```

};

```
<p className={'text-success' +  styles.ff}>Uthaya</p>
```

I tried this way but not working

"text-success" is boostrap class. if only this class is working combine both is not working

Can any help me fast.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to put a space after text-success

```
<p className={'text-success ' +  styles.ff}>Uthaya</p>
```

otherwise it will append the first thing from styles.ff to text-success and be one class that doesn't exist!